# How do I automatically populate a matrix with intervals given the size and number of the intervals?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, matrix

```
bucket_size <- 30
bucket_amount <- 24
matrix(???, bucket_amount, 2)
```

I'm trying to populate a (bucket_amount x 2) matrix using the interval size given by bucket_size. Here is what it would look like with the current given values of bucket_size and bucket_amount.

```
[1    30]
[31   60]
[61   90]
[91  120]
    .
    .
    .
[691 720]
```

I can obviously hard code this specific example out, but I'm wondering how I can do this for different values of bucket_size and bucket_amount and have the matrix populate automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `seq` specifying the `from`, `by` as 'bucket_size' and `length.out` as 'bucket_amount' to create a sequence of values ('v1').  Append 1 at the beginning while adding 1 to the 'v1' without last element and `cbind` these two vectors to create a `matrix`

```
v1 <- seq(bucket_size, length.out = bucket_amount , by = bucket_size)
v2 <- c(1, v1[-length(v1)] + 1)
m1 <- cbind(v2, v1)
```

-outupt

```
> head(m1)
      v2  v1
[1,]   1  30
[2,]  31  60
[3,]  61  90
[4,]  91 120
[5,] 121 150
[6,] 151 180
> tail(m1)
       v2  v1
[19,] 541 570
[20,] 571 600
[21,] 601 630
[22,] 631 660
[23,] 661 690
[24,] 691 720
```